# .NET Standard 2.0 Nuget package for CRM REST

Tags: c#, rest, dynamics-crm, .net-standard

My team and I are working on a new netstandard 2.0 project that will make CRUD requests on XRM/Dynamics CRM (v9+). We need a new nuget that is compatible with netstandard 2.0 and makes REST calls.

We have tried the nuget Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies but we would like to avoid using the CRMContext and make REST calls passing the access token inside.

Answer (score 2):

Web API is built on open standards, ODATA, and you don't need to add specific assemblies to use it. You just have to compose HTTP requests for specific operations.

This guide can be a good starting point https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/use-microsoft-dynamics-365-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is transitioning with v9 of CRM to give more parity to the new WebAPI accesses and will probably eventually phase out the organization service which is supported via the SDK lib